# Minecraft Plugin - Chunk generation lagging on random teleport

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a UHC Plugin, and I have a problem when I want to teleport all the players. Chunks aren't loaded for the players. They then lag for about 7 seconds, falling in the void before they can move.
After some research, I've seen that chunks are loaded for a range of 10, which can be modified in the `server.properties`.

So here is my code:

```
public class RTPCommand implements CommandExecutor {

Main main;
int i, j, x, z;
World world;
Player player;

public RTPCommand(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("rtp") && sender instanceof Player){
        player = (Player) sender;
        Random random = new Random();
        x = random.nextInt(10000);
        z = random.nextInt(10000);
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("X : " + x + " // Z: " + z);
        i = x - 160;j = z - 160;
        new TaskTimer().runTaskTimer(main, 0, 2);
    }
    return false;
}

class TaskTimer extends BukkitRunnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Chunk chunk = world.getChunkAt(i, j);
        chunk.load(true);
        j += 16;
        if(j == (z + 160)){
            if(i == (x + 160)){
                cancel();
                System.out.println("FINI.");
                player.teleport(new Location(world, x, world.getHighestBlockYAt(x, z), z));
            }else{
                i += 16;
                j = z - 160;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When the command /rtp is executed, it loads the chunks for a range of 10 around the player.
I also registered the chunkLoadEvent, and made a `System.out.println(chunk);` at each loaded chunk.
So I've for example `x = 6600`, `z=7520;` I load all the chunks, and it works, and when the player is teleported, I see that chunks are loaded in the console (with the `ChunkLoadEvent`). But it is the chunk of `x=40`,`z=150`. This does not make sense. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: This is likely a problem with the players, where they still didn't load the chunk on their client. Did you verify that this is happening to more than one player?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've modified my plugi, now it teleports all the player at a random location, but still the lag ,and for the 2 players. Here is the modified code: https://pastebin.com/EuYxiZx6 Thanks

Comment: One thing to note, chunk coords are slightly different in the way they work. You probably already know that, though. `world.getChunkAt(new Location(world, x, 256, z))` will get the chunk from a block location, rather than chunk coords. Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Chunks are not Location.

The chunk is 1/16 of the location so your example x = 6600, z=7520  Will be a chunk location of x=412 z= 470

Similarly the chunk coordinates of x=40,z=150
equal a range of x/z in world of x=640-656 z=2400-2416